# AWS cloudfront s3 is very slow

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I have a reactJS application which is stored in AWS S3 and deployed over AWS cloudfront.

The app is very slow on AWS.

What is a bestpractise to increase the speed? hosting on a EC2 or?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://status.aws.amazon.com/

11:48 AM PDT We’re investigating longer than usual propagation times for changes to CloudFront configurations. End-user requests for content from our edge locations are not affected by this issue and are being served normally.
12:52 PM PDT We have identified the root cause of the longer than usual propagation times for changes to CloudFront configurations. We continue to work toward resolution.
1:18 PM PDT Between 8:50 AM and 12:59 PM PDT, we experienced longer than usual propagation times for changes to CloudFront configurations. The issue has been resolved and the service is operating normally.

Comment: *"End-user requests for content from our edge locations are not affected by this issue and are being served normally."*

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much information to tell why app is slow.

1. Are you connecting to the correct edge location ?
2. Is it HIT from cache or MISS ? Whats your TTL configuration on CloudFront and are there cache-control metadata added to S3 object ?
3. Compress JS on CF or upload compressed on S3.

Comment: Can you explan me how to check 1 and how to setup 2?

Its a bundled application so it should be compresssed